# php replace PHP_EOL

Tags: php

The input is from a file. I'm using this code:

```
$inputText = "a\nb\nc\nd";
$outputText = str_replace(PHP_EOL, ("<br />".PHP_EOL), $inputText);
```

The output is:

```
a
<br />b
<br />c
<br />d
<br />
```

but I need:

```
a<br />
b<br />
c<br />
d<br />
```

Can somebody help me pls?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br).

This will do all the work for you.  No need for manual replacing.

```
$outputText = nl2br($inputText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
$outputText = str_replace("\n", "<br />\n", $inputText) . '<br />';
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) for this?

```
$outputText = preg_replace("/\n|$/", "<br />".PHP_EOL, $inputText);
```